# Spring Data JPA: deleteById does not delete record from database but derived delete method does

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm observing a kind of strange behavior in my Spring application. Unfortunately I cannot share the complete code, but basically this is what it looks like:

```java
// the repository
@Repository
public interface InboxRepo extends JpaRepository<Inbox, Long> {}

// the service
@Transactional
public void deleteInbox(long id) {
    inboxRepo.deleteById(id);
}
```

When calling `deleteInbox()`, there is no exception or any kind of error but the `Inbox` item is not deleted from the database. Setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` shows that there isn't even a `DELETE` statement, i.e. for whatever reason, the code doesn't actually issue the deletion.

When defining a derived delete method in the repository, then the deletion works, but it doesn't yet make sense to me:

```java
@Repository
public interface InboxRepo extends JpaRepository<Inbox, Long> {

    // this seems to work
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Inbox i where i.id = ?1")
    void delete(long id);
}
```

Dleting directly via an `EntityManager` also works. But what could be the reason that the "standard" `JpaRepository` methods don't work here?

Comment: do other repo methods work properly?

Comment: Yes, other repos are working fine. I suspect it's some kind of related entity...

Comment: the question was about other methods of the same repo, not about other repos) but never mind)
considering `deleteById` internally does `findById` (and `EmptyResultDataAccessException` will be thrown in case of an entity absence) do you see generated `select ...` query in the log? if not it's possible that `delete` query actually has been generated and performed but for some reason the entity has not been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the root cause. There was another entity having a reference to `Inbox` like this:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "inbox", cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Inbox> inbox = new HashSet<>();
```

The `FetchType.EAGER` in combination with the cascade caused the problem, i.e. as soon as the `Inbox` was deleted, this reference caused the `Inbox` to get "re-persisted". Setting `FetchType.LAZY` resolved the problem.